# SQL Server: Find the group of records existing in another group of records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL Server and I searched for a solution to find, if a group is included in another group.

The query result should be grp_id 2 because 'A'+'B' is included in grp 3 and 5.

The result should be the grp_id of the the groups, that are included in other groups. With this result i´ll make an update of another table, joined with the grp_id.

The result should be:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
|  2 |
+----+
```

I stuck in SQL because I do not find a solution to compare the groups. The idea was using bitwise comparison. But for that I had to add the value of each item in a field. I think there could be an easier way.

Thank you and best regards!
Eric

```
create table tmp_grpid (grp_id int);
create table tmp_grp (grp_id int, item_val nvarchar(10));

insert into tmp_grpid(grp_id) values (1);
insert into tmp_grpid(grp_id) values (2);
insert into tmp_grpid(grp_id) values (3);
insert into tmp_grpid(grp_id) values (4);
insert into tmp_grpid(grp_id) values (5);

--
insert into tmp_grp(grp_id, item_val) values (1, 'A');
insert into tmp_grp(grp_id, item_val) values (2, 'A');
insert into tmp_grp(grp_id, item_val) values (2, 'B');
insert into tmp_grp(grp_id, item_val) values (3, 'A');
insert into tmp_grp(grp_id, item_val) values (3, 'B');
insert into tmp_grp(grp_id, item_val) values (3, 'C');
insert into tmp_grp(grp_id, item_val) values (4, 'A');
insert into tmp_grp(grp_id, item_val) values (4, 'C');
insert into tmp_grp(grp_id, item_val) values (4, 'D');
insert into tmp_grp(grp_id, item_val) values (5, 'A');
insert into tmp_grp(grp_id, item_val) values (5, 'B');
insert into tmp_grp(grp_id, item_val) values (5, 'E');
```

Comment: Could you give us more detail about you expect result logic?

Comment: The result should be the grp_id of the the groups, that are included in other groups. With this result i´ll make an update of another table, joined with the grp_id.

Comment: Thank you for giving us the table structure and data. Could you also include the expected result in tabular format from this data..?  Also, include what you have tried so far.
[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50297153/6327676)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geez!

Technically speaking, group one is found in all other groups right? So, first a cross join to itself would be best with the condition that the values are the same AND that the groups are different, but before we do that we need to know how many items belong to each group so that's why we have the first select as a group that includes the count of elements per group, then join that with the cross join...Hope this helps.

```
select distinct dist_grpid
from 
    (select grp_id, count(*) cc from tmp_grp group by grp_id) g
    inner join 
(
select dist.grp_id dist_grpid, tmp_grp.grp_id, count(*) cc
from 
    tmp_grp dist
    cross join tmp_grp 
where
    dist.item_val = tmp_grp.item_val and 
    dist.grp_id != tmp_grp.grp_id
group by
    dist.grp_id, 
    tmp_grp.grp_id
) cj on g.grp_id = cj.dist_grpid and g.cc = cj.cc
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it can be the solution. Will try to understand the solution and usw it with the real data!